# Python: a script to find the website language

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

Hello everyone,

I am trying to write a program in Python to automatically check a website language. My script looks at the HTML header, identify where the string 'lang' appears, and print the corresponding language. I use the module 'requests'.

```
request = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
splitted_text = request.text.split()
matching = [s for s in splitted_text if "lang=" in s]
language_website = matching[0].split('=')[1]
print(language_website[1:3])

>>> en
```

I have tested it over several websites, and it works (given the language is correctly configured in the HTML in the first place, which is likely for the websites I consider in my research).

My question is: is there a more straightforward / consistent / systematic way to achieve the same thing. How one would look at the HTML using python and return the language the website is written in? Is there a quicker way using lxml for instance (that does not involve parsing strings like I do)?

I know the question of how to find a website language has been asked before, and the method using the HTML header to retrieve the language was mentioned, but it was not developed and no code was suggested, so I think this post is reasonably different.

Thank you so very much! Have a wonderful day,
Berti

Comment: Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), I'm sure that would make it easier/better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested to get the data from page source. This might help.

```
import lxml
request = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
root = lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)
language_construct = root.xpath("//html/@lang") # this xpath is reliable(in long-term), since this is a standard construct.

language = "Not found in page source"
if language_construct:
      language = language_construct[0]
print(language)
```

Note: This approach will not give result for all webpages, only those which contains HTML Language Code Reference.

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp for more.

Comment: Your code is great and it makes me more familiar with lxml! Thank you so very much for your help. Just two very minor things: in my case I had to specifically add: 'from lxml import html' otherwise for some reason the module was not there. And in my case I did not want something like 'en-AU' but just 'en' so I wrote 'language = language_construct[0].split('-')[0]'. Again thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```py
import requests

request = requests.head('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
print(request.headers["Content-language"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is far more elegant than mine, but it returns KeyError: 'content-language' in the case of certain websites (not wikipedia). For instance this one: http://asia.christianlouboutin.com/tw_tc/

Answer (score 0):

Combining the above responses

```
import requests
request = requests.head('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
print(request.headers.get("Content-language", "Not found in page source"))
```